# How to create Autowire with custom constructor arguments

Tags: java, spring

How to create Autowire in Spring with custom constructor arguments? following is my sample code. I am getting Could not autowire field; No default constructor found errors.I can't introduce default constructor as AbstractExecutor  class does not have default constructor.

IExecutor

```
public interface IExecutor {
    Object execute();
}
```

AbstractExecutor

```
public abstract class AbstractExecutor implements IExecutor {
    private IInputPropertyBean inputObject;
    private IOutputPropertyBean outputObject;
    public AbstractExecutor(IInputPropertyBean inputObject, IOutputPropertyBean outputObject) {
        this.inputObject = inputObject;
        this.outputObject = outputObject;
    }
    public abstract boolean isValidInput(IInputPropertyBean inputObject) ;
    public abstract  IInputPropertyBean getInputValues(IInputPropertyBean inputObject);
    public abstract  IOutputPropertyBean process(IInputPropertyBean attribute);
    public abstract  IOutputPropertyBean getOutputValues(IInputPropertyBean inputObject, IOutputPropertyBean outputObject;
    @Override
    public Object execute(){
        if(isValidInput(inputObject)){
            IInputPropertyBean inputAttribute = getInputValues(inputObject);
            IOutputPropertyBean outputAttribute = process(inputAttribute);
            outputObject = (IOutputPropertyBean) getOutputValues(outputAttribute, outputObject);
            return outputObject;
        }
    }
}
```

UserExecutor

```
@Repository("userExecutor")
public class UserExecutor extends AbstractExecutor { 
    public UserExecutor(@Qualifier("userInput") IInputPropertyBean inputObject, @Qualifier("userOutput")IOutputPropertyBean outputObject) {
        super(inputObject, outputObject);
    }

//override methods
}
```

IInputPropertyBean

```
public interface IInputPropertyBean { }
```

IOutputPropertyBean

```
public interface IOutputPropertyBean { }
```

UserInput

```
@Component("userInput")
public class UserInput implements IInputPropertyBean { //user sepecific properties }
```

UserOutput

```
@Component("userOutput")
public class UserOutput implements IOutputPropertyBean { //user sepecific properties }
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userExecutor")
    private UserExecutor userExecutor;


    @Override
    public UserOutput userOperation(UserInput userInput, UserOutput userOutput) {
        // How to @Autowire UserExecutor with  userInput, userOutput comming in service parameter.

                //IExecutor executor = new UserExecutor(userInput, userOutput);
    //return (UserOutput) executor.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you should be able to introduce a default constructor in UserExecutor and replace your current constructor parameters with auto wired fields.

Comment: No - you are right - it won't work:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `@Autowired` on the `UserExecutor` constructor. The following will work:

```
@Repository("userExecutor")
public class UserExecutor extends AbstractExecutor {
  @Autowired
  public UserExecutor(@Qualifier("userInput") UserInput input
    , @Qualifier("userOutput") UserOutput output) { super(input, output); }
}
```

Working code available on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/39557312).

---

You will also benefit from using generics.

```
public interface IInput {}
public interface IOutput {}

public interface IExecutor<I extends IInput, O extends IOutput> {
  O execute(I i);
}

public class AbstractExecutor<I extends IInput, O extends IOutput>
       implements IExecutor<I, O> {
  private final I input;
  private final O output;

  protected AbstractExecutor(I input, O output) {
    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;
  }

  public O execute(I i) {
    ...
  }
}

@Component
public class UserInput implements IInput {}
@Component
public class UserOutput implements IOutput {}
@Repository
public class UserExecutor extends AbstractExecutor<UserInput, UserOutput> {
  @Autowired
  public UserExecutor(UserInput input, UserOutput output) {
    super(input, output);
  }
}

public interface IUserService {
  UserOutput execute(UserInput input, UserOutput output);
}

@Service
public UserService implements IUserService {
  private final UserExecutor executor;

  @Autowired
  public UserService(UserExecutor executor) {
    this.executor = executor;
  }

  public UserOutput execute(UserInput input) {
    return executor.execute(input);
  }
}
```

You will avoid use of `@Qualifier`, `Object` and type-casting everywhere.

Comment: Hi Manish,
Thanks for reply.
UserExecutor is creating with default instance of UserInput and UserOutput (properties are null).
But what I want is instance of  UserExecutor should create with properties set by me in UserInput and UserOutput.
I have controller layer where UserInput and UserOutput object is available with custom properties in it.
I want to create UserExecutor with UserInput and UserOutput provided by controller layer.
Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: `set by me` implies that you will create different objects at `runtime`. Constructors for Spring-managed on the other hand are called (usually once only) at application initialization. Therefore, you cannot `create` a Spring-managed bean instance with `objects populated by me` at runtime with the code you have provided in your post. You will have to add `@Scope("SCOPE_PROTOTYPE")` to `UserExecutor` and then obtain its instances as `applicationContext.getBean(UserExecutor.class, userInput, userOutput)`, where `userInput` and `userOutput` are beans you supply.